# sync latest changes from master to featuer branch

Tags: git, github

there are two branches one is release and the other is a feature on which I'm working but after making my changes I did commit and push, but earlier a few changes were made to the release branch
so how do I sync my feature branch with the changes in the release branch
I don't know what to try, tried searching but don't want to risk

feature branch was made from the release branch.

Comment: you can pull changes made in `release` branch into `feature` branch

Answer (score 1):

If you had not pushed your feature branch, you could rebase it onto the latest state of the release branch:

```
git fetch origin
git rebase release
```

Since you have already pushed your feature branch, the wisest approach is to merge the latest state of the release branch into it:

```
git fetch origin
git merge release
```

Comment: ok, the changes i pushed to my feature are not yet merged into release
so i just need to do the above commands mentioned by you and it will do the job, right?

Comment: I don't know what "do the job" means. You asked "how do I sync my feature branch with the changes in the release branch" and I answered to the extent that I can make sense of those words. I told you how to do what I think you are asking to do.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `git merge` to sync your changes to another branch.
First you should checkout to release branch, and then use `git merge feature`.
If you are not sure, you can make a new branch from feature and another new one from release, then try it using 2 new branches until successed.